# Restrict access to old version of content in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

How can I restrict access for users to **old versions** of content in Alfresco?
Only admin should be able to read content version different than the last version.

Comment: 2Houssem-Bdr: this is not the same issue, I need to control access depending on the version

Comment: Yes, CMIS and Alfresco Rest API.

Comment: Override the spring bean defining the permissions on `VersionService`?